# Sql query will give weird 'unrecognized data type (near key) error in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I haven't worked with php and mysql for a long time and my return isn't so well-received by the platform.
I created tables using `phpmyadmin` and then I used the code below the generate scripts for my tables:

```
show create table recipes
```

I dropped the tables and then started to use the generated scripts to recreate my tables, only to see that they are giving me syntax errors. This is the generated script.

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  serving varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  image_url varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  calories float DEFAULT NULL,
  tag varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  meal int NOT NULL,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY user_id (user_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY name_full_text (name),
  FULLTEXT KEY tag_full_text (tag),
  CONSTRAINT recipes_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

What I want from my table is that it use `id` as the primary key, `user_id` as the foreign key to the `users` table (which is already created), and I need two `FULLTEXT` indexes on two of the columns.

The strange thing is that I am getting syntax errors in lines 11, 12, and 13. With the main one being `unrecognized data type. (near key)`. I am also getting `a comma or a closing bracket was expected (near name_full_text). Then again,`phpmyadmin` generated this query itself and I don't know why it is not accepting it.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I was able to run this query successfully on my local Windows instance of MySQL 5.7.17. But I did it in MySQL workbench, not phpmyadmin. What version of MySQL and phpmyadmin are you running?

Comment: It's most probable that you are using an older version of `pma`

Comment: That create table worked for my phpMyAdmin, version 4.6.5.2.